# Sending multiple emails in YII using YiiMail extension

Tags: php, email, yii

I am using YiiMail Extension to send mails.
I have my default contact.php file as my view. I am able to send mails for individuals but multiple emails are not allowed here.

mycontroller-

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
    $message = new YiiMailMessage;
    $message->Body=$_POST['body'];
    $message->subject = $_POST['subject']
    $message->addTo($_POST['email']);
    $message->from = "frommail@gmail.com";
    if(Yii::app()->mail->send($message) )
        echo 'mail sent';
    else
        echo 'error while sending email';
    }
}
```

I have tried the following too-

```
foreach ($model as $value)
{
            $message->addTo($model[$value]);
}
```

It does not accept multiple email id's. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple recipients mail ids as array

```
$recipients = array('test1@example.com','test2@example.com','test3@example.com');
$message->addTo('test1@example.com');
foreach($recipients as $email) {
  $mail->AddBCC($email); // if you want more than one email 
}
```

Comment: It still says invalid email id's.

Comment: @Shravya: try with `addCc` method. Hope it will work

Comment: Its still the same. Any other way?

Comment: @Shravya: how did you tried. `addTo` with single mail and `addCc` with array of mail ids ?

Comment: Yes I have tried addCc with array of mails, but it says inavlid emailid

Comment: @Shravya : could you try exactly in the edited answer?

Comment: @Shravya : try with `addBcc` in loop

Comment: Hey its still the same. This is my edited code--
      foreach($recipients as $email) {
                $message->AddBCC($email); 
                Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
            }

Comment: @Shravya: `Yii::app()->mail->send($message);` should be outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I have checked code in Yii Mailer. They haven't given such facility. If you like to achieve then you need to extend Yii Mail. It's ultimately useless because looping in your new extended class OR looping in your controller are same.

Regards...